# MAMP LocalHost server not working

Tags: php, mamp

LocalHost shows blank page. I changed port to 80 for Apache and when I press open page, it goes to localhost/mamp just fine. When I delete /mamp, all I get is a blank page. I've tried multiple things like shutting down mamp, starting it up, restarting my machine. I've checked my folder set-up and it's fine.

I tested it by creating a new file page index.html and it opens just fine.

I have no clue why it's not opening my index.php file. Here's my block of php code from header.php that I have.

```
    <html>
    <head>
<title><?php echo $pageTitle; ?></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,700"   type="text/css">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">
    </head>
```

And here's my index.php

```
    <?php 
$pageTitle = "A store of unique t-shirts";
include('inc/header.php'); 
    ?>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: well, are you sure that file is being loaded? maybe you've got a 0-byte index.html that's taking priority.

Comment: Marc, how would I find out if I had an 0-byte index.html taking priority?

Comment: find your apache's DirectoryIndex directive(s) and see what file type comes first.

Comment: To add to @MarcB's comment, you should also be able to set the `DirectoryIndex` directive by creating a file named `.htaccess` inside the `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs` directory and placing this inside of it: `DirectoryIndex index.php` (or you can also add multiple values in the order you want the files to be looked for... e.g. `DirectoryIndex index.php index.shtml index.html`).

Answer (score 0):

Anything between `<head>` and `</head>` shouldn't show up on the page, so maybe try adding some content that would be printed on the page. For example, you could change `header.php` to this just to see if anything shows up:

```
<html>
<head>
<title><?php echo $pageTitle; ?></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,700"   type="text/css">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <p>Hello, this is content.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks jerdiggity. Not sure what my issue was but there was some type of error within my header. I think it was within my if () statements. Not sure what.